# Not able to checkout the code base from git in jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting an error while checking out the code base from Git in Jenkins

i have created the Personal access tokens in GitHub with full privilege and I am the owner of project code in Github .
While checking-out the code  base getting an error like below

*Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.houston.softwaregrp.net/206206/my-app.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing*
 https://github.houston.softwaregrp.net/206206/my-app.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

[image: gitRepo configuration details]

Can someone help me what mistake I am making ?

Jenkins version:2.40 running on tomcat

[image: The plugin of GIt used in jenkins]

Comment: The same error message you are getting after building the Job and While configuring the Job

Comment: I am getting while configuring itself  is it anything do with the git plugin I am using in Jenkins

Comment: Install git in Jenkins master too...

Comment: the git version 1.7.1 is running on the master and slave boxes

Comment: try to upgrade the git to 2.x

Comment: with git 2.1 also ,  i found the issue, the issue is due to git plugin using need to downgrade the plugin